# What do Get-WMIObject \ Get-CimInstance actually do?

Tags: powershell, visual-c++, com, wmi, get-wmiobject

I have developing a new WMI instance provider and I am having a bit of trouble. I am able to register my provider successfully using `regsvr32.exe`. The `regsvr32` application calls my implementation of [`DllRegisterServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/olectl/nf-olectl-dllregisterserver) and creates the following registry keys and values:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{00000001-0000-0000-0000-00000000000F}                : (default)      = "WMI Provider"
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{00000001-0000-0000-0000-00000000000F}\InprocServer32 : (default)      = "C:\MyWmiProvider.dll"
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{00000001-0000-0000-0000-00000000000F}\InprocServer32 : ThreadingModel = Neutral
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{00000001-0000-0000-0000-00000000000F}\Version        : (default)      = 1.0.0
```

*(Where `{00000001-0000-0000-0000-00000000000F}` is just a test Class ID (CLSID))*

I am also able to successfully add my WMI class definitions defined in my **M**anaged **O**bject **F**ormat (MOF) file by using [`mofcomp.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/mofcomp). I am able to verify that my definitions are present in the WMI repository by running the following command:

```
Get-CimClass -Namespace "root/MyNamespace" | Where-Object CimClassName -like "MyClass_*"
```

Here is an example of what my MOF file looks like:

```
#pragma namespace("\\\\.\\root\\MyNamespace")
#pragma autorecover

instance of __Win32Provider as $P
{
    Name = "MyWmiProvider";
    ClsId = "{00000001-0000-0000-0000-00000000000F}";
};

instance of __InstanceProviderRegistration
{
    Provider = $P;
    SupportsGet = FALSE;
    SupportsPut = FALSE;
    SupportsDelete = FALSE;
    SupportsEnumeration = TRUE;
};

[dynamic, provider("MyWmiProvider")]
class MyClass_ExampleName
{
    [key]
    uint14 Id;

    [PropertyContext("Name")]
    String Name;
};
```

Now, if I run the following:

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root/MyNamespace" -Class "MyClass_ExampleName"
```

This produces the following error in PowerShell:

```
Get-CimInstance : Provider load failure  
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-CimInstance -Namespace "root/MyNamespace" -Class "MyClass_ExampleName"  
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (root/Surface:Device_Status:String) [Get-CimInstance], CimException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041013,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand
```

Likewise, there are three (3) Event Viewer logs that are generated when this command is executed:

1. > MyWmiProvider provider started with result code [0x80041013](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-error-constants#WBEM_E_PROVIDER_LOAD_FAILURE). HostProcess = wmiprvse.exe; ProcessID = 2144; ProviderPath = C:\MyWmiProvider.dll
2. > Id = {FB6B3CF7-293E-0002-9316-73FB3E29D601}; ClientMachine = RTR-USERNAME; User = MYDOMAIN\username; ClientProcessId = 19416; Component = Unknown; Operation = Start IWbemServices::CreateInstanceEnum - root\MyNamespace : MyClass_ExampleName; ResultCode = [0x80041013](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-error-constants#WBEM_E_PROVIDER_LOAD_FAILURE); PossibleCause = Unknown
3. > MyWmiProvider provider started with result code [0x80041013](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-error-constants#WBEM_E_PROVIDER_LOAD_FAILURE). HostProcess = wmiprvse.exe; ProcessID = 24636; ProviderPath = C:\MyWmiProvider.dll

*(It is shown that WMI did find the DLL correctly)*

I get similar results if I try calling `Get-WMIObject`, except the second Event Viewer log says the *"Operation"* was *"Start IWbemServices::ExecQuery - root\MyNamespace : MyClass_ExampleName"*.

**What exactly are `Get-WMIObject` and `Get-CimInstance` doing in the background?**

I have looked up the source for `Get-WMIObject` [[here]](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/c1faf1e6e10fc1ce45e84ef6f49ae7136c67a111/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management/commands/management/GetWMIObjectCommand.cs#L356) and despite the simple 6 lines, looking up the respect classes and function calls does not yield detailed specifics. My DLL interface only includes four (4) exported functions: [`DllGetClassObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-dllgetclassobject), `DllCanUnloadNow()`, `DllRegisterServer()`, and `DllUnregisterServer()`. I thought both `Get-WMIObject` and `Get-CimInstance` first made a call to [`DllGetClassObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-dllgetclassobject) in order to get the WMI class factory, however if I place a function call to save a string to a temporary file within [`DllGetClassObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-dllgetclassobject), I notice when calling these PowerShell commands that no temporary file is created.

I got even more specific by creating a new project following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992717/list-all-properties-of-wmi-class-in-c) so that I could be able to call the following:

```
DEFINE_GUID(InstanceProviderClassID, 0x00000001, 0x00000, 0x0000, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0F);

IWbemServices * pLoc = NULL;
CoCreateInstance(InstanceProviderClassID, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemServices, (LPVOID *)&pLoc);
```

The call to [`CoCreateInstance()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance) in this case was **successful**. I even noticed the temporary log file was created, indicating that [`DllGetClassObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-dllgetclassobject) was in fact called!

Even if I take a working instance provider that I have and put this same printing statement (or similarly a call to create a registry key/value) in its [`DllGetClassObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-dllgetclassobject) function, nothing is ever saved to indicate that this function is called when calling these PowerShell commands.

**1. What am I missing here?

2. Why is the [`DllGetClassObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-dllgetclassobject) function never called when executing both `Get-WMIObject` and `Get-CimInstance`?

3. Why am I able to execute [`CoCreateInstance()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance) successfully, demonstrating my provider is coded correctly, but get a *"provider load failure"* when executing one of the PowerShell commands?**

(A side note: In order to make things easy, I have labeled [all service functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wbemcli/nn-wbemcli-iwbemservices) with `WBEM_E_NOT_SUPPORTED`. When this is done in the working instance provider, I still do not see *"provider load failure,"* but rather *"not supported."*)

Comment: Did you try to run your `Get-CimInstance` command with the `-Debug` switch parameter ? You might get more insight on what is happening. Other than that, Try to do your query using `wbemtest.exe` tool ( in System32\wbem). https://stackoverflow.com/a/15070084/934946

Comment: You might also try using wmic.exe if you are distrustful of PowerShell (which is likely doing the right thing).  How did you intend to use your WMI/CIM provider?  Do you get similar errors....

Comment: For investigation, I prefer [`WMIExplorer`](https://github.com/vinaypamnani/wmie2/releases) over `wmic` - it's an underrated tool.

Comment: Did you try the `New-CimInstance`? Likely the `New-*` will construct it and `Get-*` will retrieve previously constructed instances (that is how other `New-*`/`Get-*` cmdlets work). It may also be interesting to try `Get-CimClass` though I don't expect that to *call* your code.

Answer (score 2):

`Get-CimInstance` and `Get-WmiObject` both use .NET APIs to communicate with WMI. In the first case, it uses https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.management.infrastructure and in the latter case uses https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.  The main difference between these two is that the CIM APIs are cross-platform compatible, while the WMI APIs have Windows extensions to CIM that only work on Windows.

Whether you decide to use the PowerShell cmdlets, WMIC, wbemtest, or something else, they ultimately call the WMI COM API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/com-api-for-wmi to talk to WMI to talk to WMI Providers.

Did you follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/writing-an-instance-provider?  It doesn't seem like you may have implemented IWbemServices in your COM server?